# Looking for new ideas on how store encrypted Database Password on client machine

Tags: database-design, vb6, authentication

I am on project team that is maintaining a few legacy VB6 applications. These applications are installed in over 600 customers worldwide mostly in the USA. These applications all connect to a database back end but the problem is that the SQL Login ID and password are hard coded inside of the application. With these projects we are using ODBC API to connect to the database.

What we would like to do is to provide a way for the users to set their own SQL Login ID password. We have thought of using Active Directory Authentication but we have dismissed this idea due to the fact that a user would be able to connect to the database using MS Access/Excel or Crystal Reports.

We are currently working on an idea where we would store the encrypted Login ID in either a INI file or in the registry but we are not liking these solutions at all. We are looking into using a Certificate but I think that we will have the same issue as with AD Authentication.

So please lets hear your ideas not matter how strange and outlandish they may be.

Comment: You haven't mentioned - why is your current implementation a problem? Is this app actually 'legacy', or is it actively being maintained? IOW, what's the reason for change?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we are receiving more and more requests from our customers to allow them to change the database password. We are working on a newer web based applications that will eventually replace the legacy applications but there have been issues involving their development to date. What we have done in the past is to ask the customer what password they want to use and then hard code that password and create a special executable for them. This poses other issues (ie upgrades, etc).

Comment: @Mark, one app I support takes the username and password and puts it in a XML file with no obfuscation at all, much less encryption.  Before I would expend a great deal of effort encrypting the password, I'd determine what risks are for a compromised password?  Could those be mitigated by locking down the user account in the server sufficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store the user name and password in an ini file.  Use a symmetrical key encryption (like AES) with salting and then base-64 encode the results.  You can generate a true random key from [Random.org](http://www.random.org/).  If you choose this route, I can provide some assistance.

Comment: That's basicly what we do here but using RC4 instead of AES (the function is 25 lines of VB code) and hex dump instead of base64 (why bother, shorter to implement again).

Comment: Ok, the more and more I read about this the more I am being lead to this solution. Andrew, I would be very interested in seeing what type of solution you may have used in hte past.

Comment: @wqw, True, a hex dump is faster.  Didn't think about that one.  RC4, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security), has been compromised.  I doubt many end-users are that likely to hack the username and password IF they even figure out the encryption method, but just FYI.